# Refreshing a single DIV using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

There's a DIV, that display images using an external php. HTML passes the item name (user input text) to AJAX as a `POST`.

I'm trying to update only this DIV using AJAX but it refreshes the entire webpage? How can I fix this so only `<div class="imgSlots" id="auto">` is refreshed when Submit button is pressed?

php file:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $resData = htmlentities('img/'.$_POST['val1']).'/'; 
}
if( isset($resData) ) {
$files = '*.*';
$fin = glob($resData.$files);
    $counts = count($fin);
    $imgs = array();
$div= '';
foreach ($imgs as $fin) {       
        $div .= '<div class="imgSlots" id="imgSlots">';
        $div .= '<li><div class="imgSlotsInner"><input type="image" src="'.$fin.'"/><testDes>"'.basename($fin.$files).'"</testDes></div></li>';
        $div .= '</div>';  
    }
echo $div;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="searchBar">
 <form action="" method="post">
    Furniture item: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="menuList">
    List of Furniture: 
    <select id='myList' name="mList" onchange='document.getElementById("val1").value = this.value;'><option value="">Furniture Available</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/filep.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#submit').val(),
                success: function(data, status) {
                    $("#imgSlots").html('');
                    $("#imgSlots").html(data);
                }
            });
            $("imgSlots").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked javascript console if there's any error?

Comment: you code having imgslots as a class not as an ID

Comment: you don't have an element `#submit` and your last `imgSlots` doesn't have a `#` (although all should be `.`).  Check your js console as you probably have an error which is causing the form to submit. Also, wrapping `li` with `div` gives invalid html and you would get multiple ids of imgSlots which is also invalid

Comment: where is imgSlots element? You have imgSlots element in your response itself. So how come will it append the html(response) to that element?

Comment: Hi Joshi... I think you're correct. How can I fix this? I tried removing `id=imgSlots` from the PHP and adding it in a new DIV in the HTML page. But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: console shows the following.`SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead` jquery.min.js:1`
Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one`
`Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`

Answer (score 2):

you need to do some changes like below (and i hope this is what you need)

in html create div with id imgslots like below

```
<div class="imgSlots" id="imgSlots">
</div>
```

in js do like this

```
var val1 = $('#val1').val();
```

then in data

```
data: {'val1':val1},
```

and in php

```
if( isset($_POST['val1']) ){
    $resData = htmlentities('img/'.$_POST['val1']).'/';
}
```

and in loop

```
$list= '';
foreach ($imgs as $fin) {       

        $list.= '<li><div class="imgSlotsInner"><input type="image" src="'.$fin.'"/><testDes>"'.basename($fin.$files).'"</testDes></div></li>';

    }
echo $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you doing it your submit button has 2 action :

1. the submit action as a type submit button
2. the onclick action that you set from jquery

You have two options

- Override the form submit action (also remove the onclick event)

  ```
  var form = $('<My form selector>');
  form.submit(function () {    
  $.ajax({
  type: post,
  url: "your url",
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function(jsonObj){
          }
        });
  });
  ```
- The other solution is to delete the `type submit` form the button and keep you onclick event as it is. Also in ajax request in `data:` you have to put an object with the data you want to sent.